# Having a trouble integrating a html script to React app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to add this script to my Local React app

```html
<div id="position-size-calculator-956132">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.cashbackforex.com/Content/remote/remote-widgets.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> RemoteCalc({"Url":"https://www.cashbackforex.com", "TopPaneStyle":"YmFja2dyb3VuZDogbGluZWFyLWdyYWRpZW50KCMzNDM1NDAgMCUsICMyNDI4MzEgMTAwJSk7IGNvbG9yOiB3aGl0ZTsgYm9yZGVyLWJvdHRvbTogbm9uZTs=","BottomPaneStyle":"YmFja2dyb3VuZDogIzE1MTgxZDsgYm9yZGVyOiBzb2xpZCAwcHggIzJhMmUzOTsgY29sb3I6ICM5MTk0YTE7","ButtonStyle":"YmFja2dyb3VuZDogIzM0MzU0MDsgY29sb3I6IHdoaXRlOyBib3JkZXItcmFkaXVzOiAyMHB4Ow==","TitleStyle":"dGV4dC1hbGlnbjogbGVmdDsgZm9udC1zaXplOiA0MHB4OyBmb250LXdlaWdodDogNTAwOw==","TextboxStyle":"YmFja2dyb3VuZDogIzE1MTgxZDsgY29sb3I6ICM5MTk0YTE7IGJvcmRlcjogc29saWQgMHB4ICM5MTk0YTE7","ContainerWidth":"665","DefaultInstrument":"EUR-USD","HighlightColor":"rgba(0,0,0,1.0)","IsDisplayTitle":false,"IsShowChartLinks":true,"IsShowEmbedButton":true,"CompactType":"large","Calculator":"position-size-calculator","ContainerId":"position-size-calculator-956132"});</script>
</div>
```

I already tried to use the `react-helmet` library and do this code but I got `Parsing error: '}' expected.` error on this `RemoteCalc` function.

```js
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

const PositionSizeCalculator = () => {
  return (
    <div id="position-size-calculator-956132">
      <Helmet>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.cashbackforex.com/Content/remote/remote-widgets.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript"> RemoteCalc({"Url":"https://www.cashbackforex.com", "TopPaneStyle":"YmFja2dyb3VuZDogbGluZWFyLWdyYWRpZW50KCMzNDM1NDAgMCUsICMyNDI4MzEgMTAwJSk7IGNvbG9yOiB3aGl0ZTsgYm9yZGVyLWJvdHRvbTogbm9uZTs=","BottomPaneStyle":"YmFja2dyb3VuZDogIzE1MTgxZDsgYm9yZGVyOiBzb2xpZCAwcHggIzJhMmUzOTsgY29sb3I6ICM5MTk0YTE7","ButtonStyle":"YmFja2dyb3VuZDogIzM0MzU0MDsgY29sb3I6IHdoaXRlOyBib3JkZXItcmFkaXVzOiAyMHB4Ow==","TitleStyle":"dGV4dC1hbGlnbjogbGVmdDsgZm9udC1zaXplOiA0MHB4OyBmb250LXdlaWdodDogNTAwOw==","TextboxStyle":"YmFja2dyb3VuZDogIzE1MTgxZDsgY29sb3I6ICM5MTk0YTE7IGJvcmRlcjogc29saWQgMHB4ICM5MTk0YTE7","ContainerWidth":"665","DefaultInstrument":"EUR-USD","HighlightColor":"rgba(0,0,0,1.0)","IsDisplayTitle":false,"IsShowChartLinks":true,"IsShowEmbedButton":true,"CompactType":"large","Calculator":"position-size-calculator","ContainerId":"position-size-calculator-956132"});</script>
      </Helmet>
    </div>
  )
}
```

PS: This script work well on html file

Comment: Where did you get that script from? What is `RemoteCalc`?

Comment: It is a Position Size Calculator widget from https://www.cashbackforex.com/tools/position-size-calculator-widget, I don't know what is it, they don't show any Documentation. this script work perfectly on a html file, and I just want to add it in React.